HttpClient adding slash before query params in URL
Using angular 18 I am trying to send a GET request to my api.
export class ClinicAnalyticsService {

  private routeBase : string = `${environment.apiBase}/api/analytics`

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getAll = (page: number) : Observable<ClinicService> => 
    this.http.get(`${environment.apiBase}/api/analytics`, {
      params: new HttpParams()
        .set('page', page)
        .set('limit', 10)
    }).pipe(
      map(({data}: any) => ({
          ...data,
          count: data.count,
          analytics : data.analytics.map((clinic: any) => ({...clinic, page}))
        })
      )
    )


I have tried adding query parameters without using HttpParams
`${this.routeBase}?page=${page}&limit=10`

I have tried adding query parameter with the HttpParams library as seen above. For some reason both outcomes produce this URL
http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/analytics/?page=1&limit=10
why is this occuring?

Check in your environment variables file (or other) what is the value of environment.apiBase. Might be ending with "/"

@underflow I have updated the code to show how the base url is constructed

Could also have something to do with the webserver configuration. Do you notice any redirects happening from http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/analytics -> http://127.0.0.1:5000/api/analytics/

@JayLane yes I get a xhr/redirect from disk cache after the initial call

is the redirect specifically adding a forward slash to the end of the url?

I'm not using angular, but had many similar issues with React/React-Router with a whole different set of behaviors when compiled and deployed to IIS.  Maybe not the best solution, but I went with the route of putting the api base in a configuration file and reading it at runtime.  Note: in dev mode, I had the VITE server proxy set to my dev server target.  Here are the functions I used, in case you find them useful:
    let webSettings: any | undefined = undefined;

const fetchWebSettings = async () =>
{
    if ( !webSettings )
    {
        const route = 'config/web-config.json';
        const response = await fetch(
            route, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                //'mode': "no-cors"
            }
        } );

        if ( !response.ok )
        {
            throw new Error( `Failed to load: ${ route }` );
        }

        const settings = await response.json();
        webSettings = settings;
    }

    return webSettings;
};

export const getApiTarget = async () =>
{

    let target = "/api/";

    /// - in production mode, fetch the web api address from web-config.json
    if ( import.meta.env.MODE !== 'development' )
    {
        const webSettings = await fetchWebSettings();
        target = `${ webSettings.apiTarget }/`;
    }

    return target;

};

To reference the config:
    const apiTarget = await getApiTarget();
    const apiRoute = `${apiTarget}route/call`;

